# Fitting a vector-valued model using Mathematica

Tags: fitting

I'm wondering if there is a way within Mathematica to perform some kind of parameter fitting on a vector-valued model function (in this case a model of electric field vectors). Essentially what I want to do is replicate the functionality of

```
NonlinearModelFit[{{x_11,x_12,...,y_1},{x_21,x_22,...,y_2},...},form,{p_1,...},{x_1,...}]
```

Except `y_i` and form are now vectors. Is there a way to do this kind of fit? I've already tried creating a scalar function that takes `i` as an argument and returns the `i`th component of the vector function (using `KroneckerDelta`), but this gives nonsensical results for the fitted model.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Can you provide an example model and data to be used in an answer?

Comment: At worst, you could always form the expression for $\chi^2$ and use `NArgMin[]`/`FindArgMin[]`…